# Code not performing user input and calling the functions from my library class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am looking to set up a Library class which will set up an array or array list of Book objects and carry out appropriate functions such as adding a book, editing a book’s details, deleting a book, loaning a book and returning a book. Also, I wish to implement a tester class which will fully test the solution. I want each option of the test menu to be programmed to include validation, where appropriate, and call the functions created in the library class. So far I have the following classes:

Book class:

```
public class Book {

    // Instance variables
    private int BookID;
    private String Title;
    private String Author;
    private boolean On_Loan;
    private int Number_of_Loans;

    // Constructor
    public Book(int BookID, String Title, String Author, boolean On_Loan, int Number_of_Loans) {
        this.BookID = BookID;
        this.Title = Title;
        this.Author = Author;
        this.On_Loan = On_Loan;
        this.Number_of_Loans = Number_of_Loans;
    }

    public Book(int iD, String title2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    // Mutator methods
    public void setBookID(int BookID) {
        this.BookID = BookID;
    }

    public void setTitle(String Title) {
        this.Title = Title;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String Author) {
        this.Author = Author;
    }

    public void setOn_Loan(boolean On_Loan) {
        this.On_Loan = On_Loan;
    }

    public void setNumber_of_Loans(int Number_of_Loans) {
        this.Number_of_Loans = Number_of_Loans;
    }

    // Accessor methods
    public int getBookID() {
        return BookID;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return Author;
    }

    public boolean getOn_Loan() {
        return On_Loan;
    }

    public int getNumber_of_Loans() {
        return Number_of_Loans;
    }
}
```

Library class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Library {

    private ArrayList<Book> books;

    public Library(ArrayList<Book> books) {
        super();
        this.books = books;
    }

    public ArrayList<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(ArrayList<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }

    public void displayBooks() {
        for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("ID " + books.get(i).getBookID());
            System.out.println("Title " + books.get(i).getTitle());
        }
        System.out.println("Displayed " + books.size() + " Books");
    }

    public void addBook(int ID, String title) {
        books.add(new Book(ID, title));

    }

    public void loaning_A_Book(int bookIndex) {
        Book book = books.get(bookIndex);
        book.setOn_Loan(true);
    }

    public void removeBook(int id) {
        boolean successful = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
            if (books.get(i).getBookID() == id) {
                books.remove(i);
                System.out.println("Book removal successful");
                successful = true;
            }
        }

        if (!successful) {
            System.out.println("Could not remove book id " + id);
        }
    }

    public void editBook(int idToEdit, Scanner s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Library tester class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Library_Tester {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Library lib = new Library(HelperUtilities.generateBooks());
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        displayMenu(lib, sc);
    }

    static void displayMenu(Library i, Scanner s) {
        System.out.println("--- Library Menu ---");
        System.out.println("--- Display Books ---");
        System.out.println("--- Add Book ---");
        System.out.println("--- Remove Book ---");
        System.out.println("--- Edit Book ---");
        System.out.println("--- EXIT ---");

        int option = s.nextInt();

        switch (option) {
        case 1:
            displayBooks();
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Enter an ID");
            int id = s.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter a title");
            String title = s.nextLine();
            i.addBook(id, title);
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("Enter an ID to remove");
            int idToRemove = s.nextInt();
            i.removeBook(idToRemove);
            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println("Enter an ID to edit");
            int idToEdit = s.nextInt();
            i.editBook(idToEdit, s);
            break;

        case 5:
            System.out.println("EXITING...");
            System.exit(1);
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid input");
            break;

        }

        displayMenu(i, s);

    }

    private static void displayBooks() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

HelperUtilities class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelperUtilities {

    private static String[] names = { "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone",
            "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets", "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban",
            "Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire", "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix",
            "Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince", "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows" };

    private static int[] ids = { 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006 };

    public static ArrayList<Book> generateBooks() {
        ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            books.add(new Book(ids[i], names[i]));
        }

        return books;
    }

}
```

My question is, ultimately, why isn't my code performing user input and calling the functions from my library class? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You should be consuming the new line character which is likely still in the stream after using `s.nextInt();`

Comment: @Oh.phil Take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like what MadProgrammer had mentioned, you need to add `s.nextLine()` after the `s.nextInt()` which is giving you problem.

If you can't decide where to insert `s.nextLine()`, change all your `s.nextInt()` to:

```
int someVariable = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
```

Receive input as String, then parse to the appropriate type. This way, your input always consumes the newline.

Comment: However, when I try to run the code I get the following exceptions:

        Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at Library_Tester.displayMenu(Library_Tester.java:21)
 at Library_Tester.main(Library_Tester.java:10)

Comment: @Oh.phil There is a different issue already. Probably because you enter String when you try to parse it to integer.

Comment: Done, thanks. How would I stop my program falling over when a string is entered?

Comment: @Oh.phil You can use exception handling for that or just do a normal validation to ensure input can be converted to numeric.